# Error : Windowed functions cannot be used in the context of another windowed function or aggregate

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get the total amount for each invoice using below query, but I got the following error:

> Msg 4109, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>   Windowed functions cannot be used in the context of another windowed function or aggregate.

**Query**

```
SELECT
  SP.InvoiceNo,
  Sum(CAST((SPD.Quantity * SPD.UnitPrice) / (SUM(SPD.Quantity * SPD.UnitPrice) OVER ()) * Sp.Shipping_Cost + (SPD.Quantity * SPD.UnitPrice) / (SUM(SPD.Quantity * SPD.UnitPrice) OVER ()) * Sp.Customs_Cost + SPD.Quantity * SPD.UnitPrice - (SPD.Discount / 100) * SPD.Quantity * SPD.UnitPrice AS decimal(10, 2))) AS [Total Amount]
FROM dbo.Stock_Purchase SP
INNER JOIN dbo.Stock_Purchase_Details SPD
  ON SP.Purchase_ID = SPD.Purchase_ID
INNER JOIN dbo.Store S
  ON SPD.Pro_ID = S.Pro_ID
  group by SP.InvoiceNo,SPD.Quantity,SPD.UnitPrice
```

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to accomplish.  Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: getting total for each invoice for example invoice #1 Total Amount 30.00 etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in error message, you cannot use `sum()over()` aggregate window function inside `sum` aggregate.

Try using a derived table

```
SELECT InvoiceNo,
       Sum(Cast(( sales ) / ( total_sales ) * Shipping_Cost + ( sales ) / ( total_sales ) * Customs_Cost + sales - ( Discount / 100 ) * sales AS DECIMAL(10, 2))) AS [Total Amount]
FROM   (SELECT SP.InvoiceNo,
               Sp.Shipping_Cost,
               Sp.Customs_Cost,
               SPD.Quantity,
               SPD.UnitPrice,
               Sum(SPD.Quantity * SPD.UnitPrice)
                 OVER()                     AS total_sales,
               SPD.Discount,
               SPD.Quantity * SPD.UnitPrice AS sales
        FROM   dbo.Stock_Purchase SP
               INNER JOIN dbo.Stock_Purchase_Details SPD
                       ON SP.Purchase_ID = SPD.Purchase_ID
               INNER JOIN dbo.Store S
                       ON SPD.Pro_ID = S.Pro_ID) a
GROUP  BY InvoiceNo,
          Quantity,
          UnitPrice
```

I guess query can be improved by adding sample data and expected result

Comment: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 17
The multi-part identifier "SP.InvoiceNo" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 18
The multi-part identifier "SPD.Quantity" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 19
The multi-part identifier "SPD.UnitPrice" could not be bound.

Comment: @Ayman - check now.. still I believe your query has logical mistakes why dont you add sample data and expected result

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want something like this:

```
SELECT SP.InvoiceNo,
       SUM(SPD.Quantity * SPD.UnitPrice * (1 - SP.Discount)) + sp.Shipping_Cost as Total_amount
FROM dbo.Stock_Purchase SP INNER JOIN
     dbo.Stock_Purchase_Details SPD
     ON SP.Purchase_ID = SPD.Purchase_ID INNER JOIN
     dbo.Store S
     ON SPD.Pro_ID = S.Pro_ID
GROUP BY SP.InvoiceNo, sp.Shipping_Cost;
```

Notes:

- The calculation for the total cost is an educated guess.  It is pretty much impossible to get the intention of the calculation from your code.
- Your `GROUP BY` has too many columns.
- There would seem to be no need for window functions for this calculation.

Comment: @Ayman . . . As I said already, edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  Your code (and hence question) makes no sense.